# How to search a word in a text and save a paragraph in pyton?

Tags: python, text, paragraph, xml.etree

The file can be downloaded from here: https://easyupload.io/dhg1ae
Change root import_xml = 'root_donload/enwiki-latest-pages-articles-multistream14.xml-p7697595p7744800'

I have my python program that parses an xml and print...

```
from lxml import etree
import csv
import wikitextparser as wtp
import re

lista = []

def set_wikilinks(self):
    tree = etree.parse(self.input_xml)
    root = tree.getroot()
    # iterate through all the text
    for page in root.findall(".//page", namespaces=root.nsmap):
        title = page.findall(".//title", namespaces=page.nsmap)
        title = title[0].text
        for text in page.findall(".//text", namespaces=page.nsmap):
            if text.text is None or len(text.text.strip())==0:
                continue
            parsed = wtp.parse(text.text)
            for section in parsed.sections:
                section_title = section.title.strip()
                section_text = section.string.strip()


                for match in re.findall('San Francisco Chronicle', section_text):    

                    print('Found "%s"' % section_text)

input_xml = '/Users/prosy/.keras/datasets/enwiki-latest-pages-articles1.xml- 
p1p30303/enwiki-latest-pages-articles1.xml-p1p30303'

processor = WikiLinkTextProcessor(input_xml)
processor.set_wikilinks()
```

When I search for the word "San Francisco Chronicles" it shows the following text, 
two paragraphs:

```
===2000 to present===

Passing as white in the 21st-century is more controversial: it is often seen as a rejection of 
blackness, family and culture.</ref>

===Passing as Indigenous Americans===

[[Image:Grey Owl.jpg|right|thumb|Portrait of Archibald Belaney, who [[Cultural 
 [[First Nations]] people, passing as an indigenous person for 
many years.]]accessdate=January 2, 2016 |work=San Francisco Chronicle |date=August 15, 2015}}</ref>"
```

But I just need it to show

```
===Passing as Indigenous Americans===

[[Image:Grey Owl.jpg|right|thumb|Portrait of Archibald Belaney, who [[Cultural 
 [[First Nations]] people, passing as an indigenous person for 
many years.]]accessdate=January 2, 2016 |work=San Francisco Chronicle |date=August 15, 2015}}</ref>"
```

The output has to be the one paragraph where it appears with its headline. How can it be done?.
Thx.

UPDATE: The file XML is mediaWiki: https://dumps.wikimedia.org/enwiki/latest/enwiki-latest-pages-articles1.xml-p1p30303.bz2
The web is :https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Air_Corps_Tactical_School
Add: root with file xml

I do two different searches:
The first one I search by title and its output is the title and the paragraph, that works.

The second one I search directly in the text so I have the title and all the paragraphs and I only need the paragraph where the keyword is found.
When i search by section.title then i´ve the paragraph becasuse it.

The first and second outputs have to be equal.

Ouput:

[image]

Comment: I have updated and added more explanations.

Comment: Add: root with file xml and ouput img. Thx